# Preallocate string memory in PHP

Tags: php, memory-management, string-concatenation

Is it possible to preallocate memory for a string in PHP or to set a string to a constant fixed size?

I have a random string that is generated, it's always 32 chars long, and it currently concatenates a character on the end of the string; I'm thinking that it would be more efficient if I could use a constant sized string.

Comment: If you have to worry about such tiny optimizations, PHP is probably the wrong language to be using in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [**`str_repeat()`**](http://www.php.net/str_repeat) to pre-generate a string containing 32 spaces, and, then, access each character like this :

```
$string[3] = 'a';
```

Note: see [**String access and modification by character**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr) in tha manual, about that.

I suppose it would cause less memory (re-)allocations.

But, really :

- you shouldn't worry about that kind of micro-optimization...
- I'm not sure how strings are implemented in PHP *(you'd have to take a look at its source-code)*, so not sure this idea would be better for performances.

Comment: Thanks. Just tested it out and concatenation is about 30% faster... go figure. I'll probably look at the source sometime this weekend.